# Why doesn't this circuit simulation work?

Tags: digital-logic, encoder, proteus, decoder, truth-table

I am trying to build a circuit using only encoders and decoders. This circuit  will output the 1’s complement of 3 bit number. (For example: If I give it 010 it will give output 101.)

I used a 741LS138 3 to 8 decoder and an 8 to 3 encoder (the 8 to 3 encoder is working fine.)

The problem is that it does not show the desired output.

When I try to provide input the output always stays 0.

I have made a truth table. I cannot figure it out what is wrong with it.

The circuit that I made:

[image]

Truth table:

[image]

Here is the schematic of the 8 to 3 encoder which I built:

[image]

Comment: "*Problem is it is not showing desired output.*" Well tell us what it *is* showing. That will be important information in debugging your problem. [Edit] it into your question.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=3+to+8+decoder

Comment: Have you set E1 high and checked good connection to E2 as it is gray?

Comment: "I am trying to build a circuit using only encoders and decoders" - but you're not using only encoders & decoders, you have a handful of inverters there too - which makes me wonder why bother with the encoders & decoders instead of just inverting the 3 bits ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone

I finally figured it out. I have constructed 1 encoder and decoder then followed truth table. It works just fine.
[image]